# Do ～せずに～したほうがいい and ～しながら～しないほうがいい have identical meaning?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Do the following sentences have identical meaning?

A: チャットせずに勉強したほうがいいです。

Edit:

B: 勉強しながらチャットしないほうがいいです。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A「チャットせずに勉強したほうがいいです。」

can be parsed in two ways:

1. [チャットせずに/しないで][勉強]したほうがいい　← 「勉強」 is stressed.
   → *lit.* "You should [not chat] [but study]."
   → What you should do is チャットしない and 勉強する.
   → "You shouldn't chat, but should study."

   So, you might say this to mean 「チャットやめなさい。勉強しなさい。」 to someone chatting and procrastinating.
2. [チャットせずに/しないで勉強]したほうがいい　← 「チャットせずに」 is stressed.
   → *lit.* "You should [study without chatting]."
   → What you should do is チャットしないで勉強, in other words, what you shouldn't do is チャットしながら勉強.
   → "You shouldn't chat while studying." / "You shouldn't study and chat at the same time."

   So, you might say this to mean 「チャットしながら勉強するのは、やめなさい。」 to someone chatting while studying.

> B「チャットしながら勉強しないほうがいいです。」

can only be parsed one way:

1. [チャットしながら勉強]しないほうがいい
   → "You shouldn't chat while studying." / "You shouldn't study and chat at the same time."

So, sentence A-2 can be used to mean the same thing as sentence B:
「勉強するときは、/ 勉強中は、チャットしてはいけません。」

---

*Edit:*

> チャットしながら勉強するな
>   勉強しながらチャットするな

I think they can be used to mean almost the same (like, don't chat and study at the same time), but I feel like チャットしながら勉強するな might be a bit closer to 勉強しているときにチャットするな, 勉強中にチャットするな, "Don't chat while studying." Compare:

- 「音楽を聴きながら食事する」≂「食事中に音楽を聴く」「食事しているときに音楽を聴く」 (listen to music while eating), rather than 「音楽を聴いているときに食事する」(← sounds strange)
- 「足元に注意しながら進む」≂「進むときに足元に注意する」 (watch your step as you move forward), rather than 「足元に注意するときに進む」「進みながら足元に注意する」

Answer (score 1):

No, they are different.

A: チャットせずに勉強したほうがいいです。is translated as " It is better to study without doing chat.

B: チャットしながら勉強しないほうがいいです。is translated as " It is better not to study with doing chat.

Answer (score 1):

No they do not have an identical meaning.

Let's see how things turns out when you write them in english.

- A: You should avoid chatting while studying.
- B: You should not chat while studying.

What do you say ?

Comment: For some reason, 「勉強しながらチャットするな」 and 「チャットしながら勉強するな」 sound almost the same to me, but "Don't study while chatting" and "Don't chat while studying" sound differently to my non-native ears, and I personally feel the latter is the better translation of B. What do you think? Are these two English sentences the same?

Comment: IM non-native O, I think 「勉強しながらチャットするな」 is not __correct__ ―would not be used―as in 「A しながら B するな」, `B` is the thing that matters the most. Said this way, it would be like implying that studying is bad for chatting. That is probably why you think your latter translation is the better one. Thus, I do not think they are the same, the explanation above stands in english too.

Comment: The A should be translated as : You should study without chatting.

Comment: @naruto It's hard to invent a context for "Don't study while chatting!"  Maybe if you were a tech support representative who provides tech support by chatting online, and you were goofing off at your job by studying for some classes while you chatted, your boss could say "Don't study while chatting!"

Comment: @snailboat Your explanation aligns with my intuition. As described in choco's edit, it's interesting to see both 勉強しながらチャットするな and チャットしながら勉強するな mean almost the same thing, and neither of them implies studying is bad.